# Regarding は数あれど (or possibly just あれど )

Tags: vocabulary, set-phrases

The following sentence is from a newspaper article 
メレンゲ菓子は数あれど、これほど繊細なものは珍しい。

1. あれど　＝　あるけど makes sense to me in the context, and this seems to be supported by my searches so far - is it simply a written form?
2. The full phrase "は数あれど" appears extremely common on google - is 数 here read しばしば, and is this a set phrase?

Comment: `は数あれど` is not a phrase.

Comment: @sawa: I may be wrong, but I think it's a phrase, while it is indeed not a sentence.

Comment: @Axioplase It is not. It is not even a constituent. `メレンゲ菓子は` or `メレンゲ菓子は数あれど` are each a phrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, basically. It's a literary construction (and indeed the origin of けど); basically you take the conditional stem (仮定形) of a verb (or other conjugable) and instead of attaching 〜ば you attach a 〜ど: so あれど、言えど、思えど、よけれど etc.

   Note for pedants: Technically, it's the perfective stem (已然形) we attach a 〜ど to.
2. 数 is pronounced かず here. The collocation 数ある means ‘many’.　The first half of your sentence may be translated as follows: ‘Although there are many meringues, ...’

Comment: Also note that we use "number" in a similar way in English: "There are a number of ways to serve a meringue, but the best way is..."