# What does 「感謝こそすれども」mean in this sentence?「恨むようなことはありません」

Tags: grammar, words

I came across this episode and I have no idea how to make sense of it

> 感謝こそすれども 恨むようなことはありません！

What does 「すれども」mean exactly in this sentence?

I also thought I knew what 「こそ」meant but this sentence is kind of making me double take.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78530   https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94667  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/31066

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is Xこそすれ(ども)Y(するようなこと)はない. A form closer to modern colloquialism is XすることはあってもYすることはない, which literally means *(subj.) **could/may well** do X, but never Y.* こそ is for emphasis. So it emphasize the possibility of X, and denying that of Y.

Examples:

- 感謝こそすれども 恨むようなことはありません I may well thank you, and never hate you (for that).
- 税金は上がりこそすれ、下がることはない。 Taxes always rise, but never gets reduced.

---

It seems to be one of N1 grammar, e.g. [this](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C-koso-sure-meaning/).

A [dictionary entry for こそすれ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%93%E3%81%9D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8C#:%7E:text=%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%84%E3%82%92%E4%BA%8B%E5%AE%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6,%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E7%94%A8%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82):

> ある行いを事実として一旦認める場合に用いる表現。他の物事は断じて否定するというような場合に用いられる。「憎みこそすれ、決して危害を加えたことはない」などのように用いられる。

Comment: Maybe a duplicate https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60238/45489