# Can we think of といえど as という + ど?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> そこで、「あの傘はたった一つしかない家宝なので、お殿様**といえど**譲るわけには参りませんと断りました」
>
> <sup>Therefore, I refused, saying, "That umbrella is my only family heirloom and, **even if you were a lord**, I would not give it away."</sup>

> われわれは何人**といえど**、自分が属している社会という組織から自分を切り離すことは出来ない。
>
> <sup>**No matter how many of us there are**, we cannot separate ourselves from the social organization to which we belong.</sup>

---

From [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A9), archaically, ど collocated with the stem of a verb in ば form. Seemingly, this happens to be the case with といえど because the stem of the affirmative ば form of いう is いえ, which, judging from the examples above, changes the meaning of という to a conditional one. Hence, the question: can we think of といえど as という + ど ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/regarding-%e3%81%af%e6%95%b0%e3%81%82%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a9-or-possibly-just-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8c%e3%81%a9/2712#2712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes といえど = と + いう + ど.

From [a dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A9/#jn-154703)

> ［接助］活用語の已然形に付く。
>
> １ 逆接の確定条件を表す。…が、しかし。…けれども。
>
> ２ 上の事柄を受け、それを条件として予想されることに反する事柄がいつも起こることを表す。…の場合でも、きまって。…ても。
>
> [補説]「ども」と同じ意味・用法をもつが、中古から中世にかけて、漢文訓読文系統では「ども」が多用されているのに対し、仮名日記系統では「ど」が圧倒的に多かった。中世中ごろからは女性も「ども」を多く用い、「ど」は衰えた。現代語では文章語として、「といえど」「と思えど」「待てど暮せど」など慣用的表現に用いられる。

已然形 is roughly the classical equivalent of modern 仮定形. As noted above, ど  appears mostly as set phrases in modern usage.

Comment: See also [this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%88%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-what-does-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%88%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82-mean#answer-31069) discussing the ～ど ending.